# 2002 Honda Accord Cranks but won't start

Tags: honda, accord, cranks-wont-run

I have a 2002 Honda Accord Coupe V6 3.0l

I've recently run into an intermittent issue that prevents the car from starting even though my battery has plenty of power and i'm not low on gas.

When this occurs, i seem to have an issue with the shift interlock system. under normal circumstances (ie when the car starts), you hear the solenoid click and will shift with the brake pressed, however when it refuses to start, i don't hear the click and when i press the brake pedal down the shifter remains locked.

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Can you describe what you see and hear while you try to start the engine?  E.g which lights are on dash, starter making a noise etc.

Comment: The engine cranks but doesn't turn over. doesn't sound any different from how it normally starts apart from the lack of combustion. And there's nothing peculiar about the dash lights when i attempt to start.